# How to get user password?

Tags: nebula-graph

After using the `CREATE USER` command to create a user, what command can be used to obtain the new user's password?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can somehow return the password of any user in the NebulaGraph database. You can set the password for a user when creating it, for example `CREATE USER user1 WITH PASSWORD 'nebula'`, or reset the password with the GOD role after the user is created, for example `ALTER USER user1 WITH PASSWORD 'nebulagraph';`.